# In vi, how can I navigate to the function declaration?

Tags: vi

In Vi, if I am in the middle of a function, how can I navigate back to the function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I'd typically use `{`, which gets me to the beginning of the paragraph (which is often the beginning of the function too) in one keystroke, or sometimes I might have to use `{` two or more times, depending on how many blank lines I have in the function.

If I'm using C and *ctags*, then `:tag functionname` will get me to the function declaration from anywhere ([Vim Book, p.79](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious, this may depend on the language and the coding style. 
If the code is in C or C++ and the programmer followed the convention of beginning functions as

```
int
sum(int num1, int num2)
{
```

(or even with the return type on the same line as the function name), and then indenting all internal blocks, you could do a `?^{` search.  Alternatively **(and this may be the best answer)**, `[[` seems to be a shortcut for `?^{`.  (`]]` seems to be a shortcut for `/^{` –– no, *not* `/^}`.)

Even if the convention is

```
int sum(int num1, int num2) {
```

(consistently) you could search for `?^[a-zA-Z].*{$`. For that matter, `?^[a-zA-Z]` might be good enough.  Other languages, other coding conventions might require different answers.